# AsyncTask "onPostExecute" never gets called

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I searched through all the postswith nearly the same question, but couldn't find anything helpful :\

I made an own interface to implement a "TaskListener" into my MainActivity. My idea was to run the `onTaskComplete()`-method in the main thread, after the AsyncTask finished.

My interface:

```
public interface TaskListener {
    void onTaskComplete();
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TaskListener{
      private MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask;

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);
           //Some other stuff here
      }

      private void aMethod(){
          myAsyncTask.execute(aString);//aString is of course defined
      }

      public void onTaskComplete(){
          MyClass tmpMyObject = null;
          try{
              tmpMyObject = myAsyncTask.get();
          }
          catch(Exception e){
              //...
          }
      }
}
```

MyAsyncTask:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MyClass>{
      private TaskListener taskListener;

      public MyAsyncTask(TaskListener taskListener){
           this.taskListener = taskListener;
      }

      protected MyClass doInBackground(String... aString){
           //Some code here
           MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
           return myObject;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(MyClass myObject){
           taskListener.onTaskComplete();
      }
}
```

If I run my app, it returns `myObject` at `doInBackground()`, but the `onPostExecute()` never gets called. So I tried a few things like that in `MainActivity`:

```
private void aMethod(){
      MyClass myObject = myAsyncTask.execute()
                                    .get();
}
```

With this code the `onPostExecute()` gets called. But in this way my main-thread has to wait for the Async-Thread to finish..

Thanks a lot

Comment: IMHO, if you are using `get()` with an `AsyncTask`, that's a major code smell.

Comment: you probably should be passing the return value `myObject` back to the listener, rather than having to call `get`

Comment: How should I pass it back? I can't do that in `doInBackground()`, otherwise I got two threads working in one class, which isn't that nice :D
Or is there another way?

Comment: get method will make your main thread and background thread synchrounous..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain why do you think your onPostExecute does not get called?

I use this all the time and never had any issue. Try the below.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(MyClass myObject) {
    super.onPostExecute(myObject);
    // LOG some message or put a break point to see if you get called
    taskListener.onTaskComplete(myObject);
}
```

Change your interface to accept the MyClass as a parameter.

```
 public void onTaskComplete(MyClass myObject){
  // Do whatever you need to do with myObject
    // LOG some message or put a break point to see if you get called

  }
```

Comment: Tried it, but it also never reaches the Log in `onPostExeceute` :\

Comment: `super.onPostExecute()` is not necessary. The base implementation is empty.

Comment: I am really perplexed. As danny mentioned, this should work fine. Only thing I can think of how the AsyncTask is defined in the constructor and used later. This should be okay but at this point of time, you should be trying anything. Why don't you move defining the AsyncTask just before you use it? That is, move myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this); to aMethod before calling execute. It is also a good programming practice; avoiding unnecessary member variables and also defining them closer to where you need.

Comment: Editing my answer based on  matiash's  comment.

Comment: I did it like that (defining it right before the use of it) now, because I have to use this Task not only once ;)
But for those who are curious: It isn't necessary to do that.
I found my problem in the onCreate method. There was a wrong old method-call which caused the app to crash (this line wasn't included above) right before `onPostExecute()` would have been called. But I really have to THANK YOU, because of your code above and your help! =)

Answer (score 0):

It is not called because you didnt pass it to your callback method of your interface..
Also the get method will make your main thread and background thread synchronized..So it will wait for background thread to be done..

Comment: I just did it like Raghu explained above. What do you mean with "it"? What do I have to pass to my callback-method?
Sorry, but I don't understand exactly what you mean :\

Comment: @amorpherCoder create a parameter yes just like Raghu just did

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. I also got rid of the get-method, but nothing changed. It just returns myObject, but never calls `onPostExecute`

Comment: @amorpherCoder are you able to get the myObject?? after the background has executed?

Comment: Yep, I could set it as a public attribute of my `MyAsyncTask` and then get it from there ;)

Comment: @amorpherCoder then onpostexecute is excuted.. try to Log.d in the postexecute and youll get a response

Comment: I didn't got called, because the program crashed in the main-thread, before it would get called :\
I did a wrong method-call in onCreate, which isn't listed above, sorry. And THANK YOU! =)